# Unix/Linux Shell Grep to cut

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep, cut

I have a file, say 'names' that looks like this

```
first middle last     userid
Brian Duke Willy      willybd
...
```

whenever I use the following

```
line=`grep "willybd" /dir/names`
name=`echo $line | cut -f1-3 -d' '`
echo $name
```

It prints the following:

```
Brian Duke Willy      willybd
Brian Duke Willy
```

My question is,  how would I get it to print just "Brian Duke Willy" without first printing the original line that I cut?

Comment: What shell are you using that causes the line from the file to be printed?  The code you have posted should not give the output you show.

Comment: Run `$SHELL -x yourscript` and look at the value assigned to `line`; is one or two lines?

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this sort of thing is:

```
awk '/willybd/{ print $1, $2, $3 }' /dir/names
```

or, to be more specific

```
awk '$4 ~ /willybd/ { print $1, $2, $3 }' /dir/names
```

or

```
awk '$4 == "willybd" { print $1, $2, $3 }' /dir/names
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "willybd" /dir/names | cut "-d " -f1-3
```

The default delimiter for cut is tab, not space.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the intermediate variables, you can use

```
grep "willybd" /dir/names | cut -f1-3 -d' '
```

One of the beautiful features of linux is that most commands can be used as filters: they read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`, which means you can "pipe" the output of one command into the next command.  That's what the `|` character does.  It's pronounced *pipe*.

Comment: Funny, I ran the commands you listed, and as I expected, it didn't print the original line.  Are you sure you didn't `$echo $line`?  Otherwise, I'm not sure why my one-line version would behave differently from yours.